# What is default IPv6 configuration on routers

Tags: router, ipv6, dhcp-server, dhcpv6

I've just started learning IPv6. I have a router running OpenWrt and I would like to configure it to use IPv6. As I know this address can be assigning to a client with or without DHCPv6 server. Do you know what is the default configuration on popular routers? Which method is used? Statefull, stateless or statefull + stateless?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

You generally have a few modes:

1. SLAAC. Clients pick their own IP, based on a announced subnet, which must be a /64. They get subnet and route from the RA announcements.
2. DHCP6. Clients get only routes through RA.
3. Combination. They may use SLAAC, or DHCP. Either will work, but DHCP may provide additional useful settings.

For a client network, I'd suggest going with SLAAC or SLAAC + DHCP. For servers, it's probably a good idea to not use SLAAC, but stay with DHCP.